# Pandasデータフレームで特定行を削除する方法

Tags: python, pandas

（購買データの前処理に関するご質問です）
同「id」「購入日」「店舗」「商品」「売上タイプ」ごとに連番を振った、下記データフレームがあるのですが、

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '222', '222', '222', '333', '333', '333', '333', '333'],
                   '購入日': ['1/5', '1/5', '1/5', '1/5','1/5', '2/3', '2/3', '2/3', '3/5', '3/5', '4/1', '4/1', '4/1'],
                   '店舗': ['東京', '東京', '東京', '東京','東京', '千葉', '千葉', '千葉', '東京', '東京', '千葉', '千葉', '千葉'],
                   '商品': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   '売上タイプ': ['売上', '売上', '売上', '返品','返品', '売上', '返品', '返品', '売上', '返品', '売上', '売上', '返品'],
                   'cnt': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]})
```

このうち、
同「id」「購入日」「店舗」「商品」の、”売上” に対応する "返品" があるレコードは削除したいです。＜対応する＞とは、"売上"のcnt "1" があり、かつ、"返品" のcnt"1" がある場合です。"売上"のcnt "1" ・"返品" のcnt "1" のレコードを共に削除したい、ということです。（・・・売上cnt"2"・返品cnt"2"同士は削除、売上cnt"3"・返品cnt"3"同士は削除・・・。対応がないレコードは残す）

上記のdfに対してこの処理を行った場合、下記のデータフレームが返るイメージです。

```
ans = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['111', '222', '333'],
                    '購入日': ['1/5', '2/3', '4/1'],
                    '店舗': ['東京', '千葉', '千葉'],
                    '商品': ['A', 'B', 'D'],
                    '売上タイプ': ['売上', '返品', '売上'],
                    'cnt': [3, 2, 2]})
```

データ量が2500万件ほどあるので、処理速度も考慮しつつ書きたいと思っております、。（基本のfor文だと遅くなる・・・？）アドバイスいただける方がいらっしゃいましたらお願いいたします。

Comment: 「id」はイマイチ整合性が取れていない感じですが何の情報を表していますか？ それからこういう場合、取引伝票番号も採番・記録しておいて、返品時には対応する売上時の番号を記録するものでは無いですか？ また、売上と返品の数が違う(売上3個のうち1個だけ返品)とか日付が違うのも有り得るのでは？

Comment: 「id」は会員番号を示しています。例として適当に入れてしまいました。
また、おっしゃる通り、取引番号があれば、それをKEYに削除できるのですが、、それがないために難儀しています。。

また、売上と返品の日付が異なるものもありますが、それはレコード削除対象外とし、同日で売上・返品の組み合わせがあったもののみを削除対象としたいです。（同日の返品は、購入がなかったものとみなすため削除対象。別日の返品は、購入履歴としてデータに残しておく）

また、中には、返品データしかない場合もあります（分析には、直近１年のデータを使用するため、直近1年以上前の購入に対応する返品が、直近1年のデータに含まれてくる、といったような。その場合の返品データは、対応する売上が期間内データに存在しないので、削除対象にはしません。その形で問題ないです）

色々書いてしまいましたが、、質問本文の通り、同「id」「購入日」「店舗」「商品」の、売上⇔返品の対応が存在する場合のみ、それらのレコードを削除したい感じです。。

Comment: 二つの""売上"の[]

Answer (score 1):

グループ化した後、それぞれに含まれる「売上タイプ」の個数を `agg()` で調べます。「売上」だけ、もしくは「返品」だけの場合は `1` になりますので、「売上タイプ」の個数が `1` になるレコードを抽出します。

```py
df.iloc[
  sum((
    df.assign(idx=df.index)
      .groupby(['id', '購入日', '店舗', '商品', 'cnt'], as_index=False)
      .agg({
        'idx': lambda x: list(x) if len(list(x)) == 1 else []
      })
  ).idx, [])].reset_index(drop=True)

# 処理結果

    id 購入日  店舗 商品 売上タイプ  cnt
0  111    1/5  東京    A       売上    3
1  222    2/3  千葉    B       返品    2
2  333    4/1  千葉    D       売上    2
```

**追記**

> df.iloc[ sum(●●●).idx, [])]
>
> ilocは、数値で行と列の位置を指定するものという認識ですが(df.iloc[行, 列])、この部分のコードについて補足して下さい

こちらについては処理の途中経過を見て貰うと分かりやすいかと思います。

```py
(df.assign(idx=df.index)
  .groupby(['id', '購入日', '店舗', '商品', 'cnt'], as_index=False)
  .agg({
    'idx': lambda x: list(x) if len(list(x)) == 1 else []
  }))
=>
    id 購入日  店舗 商品  cnt   idx
0  111    1/5  東京    A    1    []
1  111    1/5  東京    A    2    []
2  111    1/5  東京    A    3   [2]
3  222    2/3  千葉    B    1    []
4  222    2/3  千葉    B    2   [7]
5  333    3/5  東京    C    1    []
6  333    4/1  千葉    D    1    []
7  333    4/1  千葉    D    2  [11]
```

ここで、idx カラムには元のデータフレーム(`df`)のインデックス値が入ります。条件に適合しない行(レコード)の場合は空リスト(`[]`)にしていますが、これは後の `sum()` のためです。

```
上述のデータフレーム.idx
=> [[], [], [2], [], [7], [], [], [11]]

sum(上述のデータフレーム.idx, [])
=> [2, 7, 11]
```

`sum(lst, [])` で「上述のデータフレーム.idx」(リストのリスト)を平坦化(flatten)しています。

```
df.iloc[上述の sum() の結果].reset_index(drop=True)
```

`sum()` の結果はリストで、これは抽出条件に適合するレコードのインデックス値(元のデータフレームの行番号)になります。このリストを `df.iloc[]` に渡す事によって目的の「行」を選択・抽出しています。

Comment: groupbyしたものを、agg()で調べるのに、列名 idx（assiginで追加した列）に対して関数を適用していますよね。こちら、['id', '購入日', '店舗', '商品', 'cnt']ごとの 'idx' の値をリストに格納して要素数を数え、1ならそのリストを返す。1以外の場合は空のリストを返す、ということをしているのですよね？３～６行目はこのように理解したのですが、右記部分がうまく解釈できません、。df.iloc[ sum(●●● ).idx, [])]　　（ilocは、数値で行と列の位置を指定するものという認識ですが（df.iloc[行, 列]）、記載いただいたこの部分のコードについて、補足いただけませんでしょうか？）

Comment: 詳細のご説明ありがとうございます。データフレームの特定の列のみについて、各行の値をそれぞれリストにできる、ということを知りませんでした。分解して実行してみて理解を深めてみたいと思います！取り急ぎ御礼まで・・・

Comment: 各行の意味をひとつずつ分解して理解し、実際の分析データに使用してみました。データは2000万行ほどあるのですが、実行後1時間以上経過しても処理が完了しません・・・。量が多い場合は向かない処理が含まれていたりしますでしょうか？？もしお分かりになりましたらアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: @miya さん、いきなり全件を処理に掛けるのではなく、いったん千, 万, 十万件くらいを切り出して処理時間を試してみてはどうでしょう？ ワンライナーな処理では意味が無いかもしれませんが、性能に関してはこんなツール [Pythonのline_profilerとmemory_profilerの紹介](https://qiita.com/aratana_tamutomo/items/aa3b723a3dd7a44e45d6) もあるので、処理を分解して何処に時間がかかっているか調べてみては？

Comment: @kunif　さん　アドバイスありがとうございます。試してみたいと思います。

Comment: @miya [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) を眺めると、`sort` というパラメータがあって、`Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off.` と書かれています。こちらを試してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: @metropolis さん、ありがとうございます、試してみたいと思います！（業務との兼ね合いで時間がかかってしまうと思いますが、、実現可否結果、またご報告させていただきます）

Answer (score 0):

概念的にはこれでいけるはずです。
ただし性能は考慮していません。

```
droprows = []
grouped = df.groupby(['id','購入日','店舗','商品','cnt'])
for i,dfw in grouped:
    r = len(dfw.index)
    if r >= 2:    ## 上記条件が同一で2つ以上の記録有り
        ## 以下は売上と返品が対になっていることの確認とその対応処理
        sale = []
        void = []
        subg = dfw.groupby('売上タイプ')
        for t,dfs in subg:
            if t == '売上':
                sale.extend(dfs.index)
            else:
                void.extend(dfs.index)
        
        slen = len(sale)
        vlen = len(void)
        blen = min(slen,vlen)
        if slen == vlen:  ## 売上と返品の記録が同件数
            droprows.extend(dfw.index)
        elif blen > 0:  ## 記録件数は違うが売上と返品が対になっているのが0ではない
            ## リストに先に現れた順番に削除する。対になっていない分は残す
            droprows.extend(sale[:blen])
            droprows.extend(void[:blen])
        ## else: どちらかが0件なら対になっていないので削除リストには追加しない

droprows.sort() ## 削除リストを昇順でソートしておく

ans = df.drop(index=droprows)
ans.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

---

**コメント対応追記：**

`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`の大元の構造については私も情報が無いですが、単一変数で受ける`for x in grouped:`とか、上記回答で書いた`for i,dfw in grouped:`のループで`print(x)`とか、`print(i)`, `print(dfw)`すると内容が見えてきます。

単一変数で受けると`グループ選択に使った値(複数条件だとそのtuple)`と、`対応するデータフレームの選択された部分`がtupleになっています。
受ける変数を分けると、それらが別々の変数に格納されます。

`データフレームの選択された部分`は、それ単独がデータフレームとして変更したり情報を取得したりと言った各種操作が出来ます。(変更は出来なかったかも、以下の件があるので未確認です)
しかし何か操作をしてそのデータフレーム自身を書き換えても、それはループの中だけでループ外には持ち出せません。
そのため別途変数(ここではdroprows)を用意して情報を保存しています。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。初歩的な質問ですみません、、groupby（）をするとpandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy objectが返ってきますが、この中身はどのようになっていますでしょうか？そのイメージができていないため、その後のfor文でインデックスと要素？を抽出していく部分の処理が完全に理解しきれません、、。ネットで調べたのですが思うような情報が見当たらず、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです・・。

Comment: ありがとうございます。まだいただいた情報すべてを理解しきれていないので、、ひとつひとつ調べながら理解を深めてみます！